# Maximum font size to fit UITextView without splitting individual words

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

How do I find the maximum font size that will enable all text to fit within a UITextView **without splitting individual words onto multiple lines**? I have found similar questions online, but all of the answers provide code that splits individual words.

I assumed the following would work, but individual words are still split onto multiple lines.

```
UIFont *tempFont = [UIFont fontWithName:font size:MIN_FONT_SIZE];

while ([snippetTextView.text sizeWithFont:tempFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textViewWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height < textViewHeight)
{
    tempFont = [tempFont fontWithSize:tempFont.pointSize + 1];
}

snippetTextView.font = tempFont;
```

Comment: If you want all of the text on one line, why use a `UITextView` instead of a `UITextField`?

Comment: @rmaddy I want text on multiple lines, but I don't want individual words split onto multiple lines.

Comment: The text view splitting words and your calculation of the font size are two completely different things. Are the words being split hyphenated or too long to fit on one line?